# Make a label bold in GTK+

Tags: c, gtk

I am simply trying to make the text bold in a `GtkLabel`. All I can find are examples for Python and C#. Here is how I currently set up `GtkLabel`s, but I don't know how to make them render the text in bold.

```
GtkWidget* label = gtk_label_new("Text I want to be bold");
```

Comment: GTK+ is a C toolkit, and this code uses it as such; it is not C++ specific at all. If you want to _really_ use GTK+ in C++, then use [`gtkmm`](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/), its official C++ binding, and its counterparts like [`libsigc++`](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/), `glibmm`, `cairomm`, etc. I recommend this massively because it gives you the power of GTK+ but with `class`es and far, _far_ less boilerplate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple way is to call [gtk_label_set_markup()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-set-markup), which accepts a string of [Pango markup](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Markup.html#pango-Markup.description):

```
GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(NULL);
gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), "<b>Text to be bold</b>");
```